# Why my read count is increasing in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase

Currently I'm only checking for the data is available or not in the firestore database. I haven't stored any data for the id I am checking for.
But still count is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the "checking for data is available" is executing a read to see that it is or isn't there.

Per Googles docs.

***Minimum charge for queries**
There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.*

Link to the doc.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge